# Golang чтение бесконечного цикла горутины в родительском потоке

Tags: golang

Есть горутина, в которой есть бесконечный цикл `for {}`, в нем происходит вызов http-запроса, при вызове запроса может произойти ошибка, можно ли ее как-то поймать в родительской горутине, передав в канал, не блокируя ее?

То есть я создал канал `errors := make(chan error, 1)`, передаю errors методу, который вызывается в горутине `go someFunc(errors)`, если делать что-то вроде `waitGroup` или `errorGroup`, то основной поток будет заблокирован, пока `someFunc` не завершит работу, так что не подходит.

В коде это примерно так выглядит

```go
func someMainFunc () error {
    errors := make(chan error, 1)
    go someFunc(errors)
    // тут нужно поймать ошибку из канала и вернуть ее из someMainFunc()
}

func someFunc(errorsChan chan error) {
    for {
        // do http request
        if err != nil {
            errorsChan <- err
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    errors := make(chan error, 1)
    go someFunc(errors)

    select {
    // тут пытаемся поймать ошибку. если она произошла, то попадет в канал errors и сработает этот триггер
    case err := <-errors:
        fmt.Printf("here error recieved. %v\n", err)

    // если вдруг ошибку не получили, то не хочется ждать бесконечно,
    // огриничиваем на 10 секунд, то есть эта секуция сработает почсле 10 секунд
    case <-time.After(10 * time.Second):
        fmt.Printf("here error did not recieved after 10 second")
    }

    // one more option
    // тут мы можем без select ждать ошибку пока не поймаем ее.
    err := <- errors
    fmt.Printf(err.Error())

}

func someFunc(errorsChan chan error) {
    for {
        err := doSomething()
        if err != nil {
            errorsChan <- err
            errorsChan <- fmt.Errorf("my custom error")
            return
        }
    }
}

func doSomething() error {
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    if rand.Int()%5 == 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("test error")
    }
    return nil
}
```

output:

```
here error recieved. test error
my custom error
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-OP82HJrwXe

я показал 2 способа поймать ошибку, в любом случае алгоритм простой.  если есть канал и мы хотим вытянуть из него информацию, то это делается через <-, например, `err := <- errors`. Если в канал попадает несколько ошибок, то нужно несколько раз запрашивать ошибку.

выбор с Select предпочтителен, так как можем обработать ситуацию, когда в канали ничего не пришло.

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю, на строке err := <-errors программа подвиснет до тех пор, пока не будет получено сообщение из канала errors ?

Comment: то есть вопрос не про то как из канала читать, это мне понятно как сделать, сам вопрос про то, как можно сделать ожидание сообщения из канала, в который сообщение отправляется в горутине в которой есть бесконечный for {}, вот только сообщение там может никогда не отправиться в канал, следовательно,  до тех пор родительская горутина будет заблокирована до получения сообщения, именно этой блокировки мне нужно избежать

Comment: первый вопрос - да. программа подвиснет до тех пор, пока не будет получено сообщение из канала errors

Comment: @sew810i9 "этой блокировки мне нужно избежать" - если вы не читаете из канала, то программа не завистнет. вам же в любом случае нужно читать?  а если прочли (получили ошибку), то что тогда? что должно произойти?

Comment: если при чтении из канала поймал ошибку в родительской горутине, то делаю return err из метода someMainFunc

Comment: по твоему примеру понял как избежать блокировки до момента, пока в канал ничего не пришло, но нужно как-то постоянно слушать канал, т.к. в него могут периодически падать ошибки. А то сейчас ведь получается, что после того, как единожды select case отработает, он уже последующие сообщения не поймает, я так понимаю, что тут только for {} бесконечный запускать в основном потоке, но если это сделать, поток основной будет блокироваться, можно ли это как-то обойти ?